# Bukkit 1.11.2 Get player who did damage to another player

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I know that you can get the damage cause with

```
event.getCause() == DamageCause.ENTITY_ATTACK
```

in the entity damage event, but I have not found a method to return the entity that did the damage. I need to find this out so I can check if the player has a certain item in their inventory.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish what you want, you should use an **EntityDamageByEntityEvent**.

Basically it's an event that fires everytime an Entity gets damaged by another Entity, and players are Entities.

---

Now, the Event Handling can be done this way:

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerDamage(EntityDamageByEntityEvent e) {
Entity damager = e.getDamager();
Entity damageTaker = e.getEntity();

if (damageTaker instanceof Player) {
    //DamageTaker is a Player
    Player taker = (Player) damageTaker;
    if (damager instanceof Player) {
        //Damage Causer is also a player
        Player damagerPlayer = (Player) damager;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`EntityDamageByEntityEvent`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/event/entity/EntityDamageByEntityEvent.html) and cast the damager to a Player

Comment: Should improve your question by adding how to use the event and how to recover the damager. The user Shouldn't need to visit another site to understand what should be done.